I'm unable to use transition: to work in a CSS component
I can't get CSS to work in one particular part of my project. Works fine with other components.
index.tsx
const toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
    
 }

return (
    ....
      
      <div className={`${styles.menu} ${menuOpen ? styles.active : ''}`}>
        <button className={styles.navTgl} onClick={toggleMenu} aria-label="toggle menu">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <nav className={styles.nav}>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Docs</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    ....

Home.module.css
.nav:before {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  clip-path: circle(30px at calc(0% + 55px) 55px);
  visibility: hidden;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.menu.active .nav:before { 
    visibility: visible;
    clip-path: circle(100%);
}

This is the logic of the code to open the menu box. I'm getting to open it, but the line
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; doesn't seem to work
I've tried using opacity and transform but doesn't change anything. Tried increasing trasition time and -webkit-transition as well

Could you provide some other details? Do you see the animation, and the nav isn't visible, or the animation doesn't work?

@SkerdiVelo The nav is visible. Only issue is the animation not coming through for this particular piece of code

@Andrew I've taken the design from codepen and this is the particular code in his css for the animation part. I'll add the link to the code with the working model.
https://codepen.io/ahmedhrayyan/pen/EremLG

@NazlulRizan given you have this working elsewhere, I'd suggest it is not a problem with the code you've shared but rather something else causing the issue. In such a situation really the best way to find the issue is to gradually remove other pieces of code until it starts working again or start with just the working nav and add bits until in breaks. Essentially you need to isolate the real issue as, based on your explanation, the real issue is not the code you've shared.
